# python: my package import fails on 3.1, but works on 2.6

Tags: python, import, python-3.x

I decided to develop my home project in python 3.x rather than 2.x. So I decided to check, if it works under 3.1. I run `python3.1` above my package directory and then:

```
>>> import fathom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "fathom/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from schema import Database
ImportError: No module named schema
```

when I enter fathom directory however schema can be imported:

```
>>> import schema
```

Also when I run `python2.6` above my package directory I can do this:

```
>>> import fathom
```

My `__init__.py` has following import:

```
from schema import Database
from inspectors import PostgresInspector, SqliteInspector, MySqlInspector
```

Should I add something for `python3.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try a [relative import](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)?

```
from . import schema
from .inspectors import PostgresInspector
```

Works in Python 2.6 as well.

The [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) script can help you pinpoint more of these problems.

Comment: Yeah, relative imports require this . at the beginning. I didn't know about this. But 2to3 worked great and corrected some other stuff too. Thanks :-)